# Where can I find pixmap of Qt MessageBox icons

Tags: qt

I am developing my own MessageBox because I need the functionality of:

`Do not display this message next time`

Which isn't supported by standard message boxes. However I would like to make it look as much as possible as original message box. Therefore I would like to reuse the same icon set you can find when message boxes are displayed.

Is there any way to retrieve this pixmap so that I can use it? Something like:

```
this->ui->icon->setPixmap(QMessageBox::questionPixmap);
```

Answer (score 2):

Although this is an old question, I found an easy solution for those seeking an answer to this.

Create a qLabel in your custom class, and then in the constructor of that class create a QIcon with the style you want, convert it into a pixmap and use the QLabel::setPixmap() function to apply it to the one you created:

```
QIcon icon = style()->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxWarning); //or 
//whatever icon you choose
QPixmap pixmap = icon.pixmap(QSize(60, 60));
ui->iconLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);

ui->iconLabel->setScaledContents(true); //you can set this to fill the 
//dimensions of your qLabel if you wish.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `QStyle::standardIcon` with `QStyle::SP_MessageBoxQuestion`.

You can get style from current `QWidget` or `QApplication`.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

This is the original source code (internal Qt implementation) that gets the pixmap for message box:

```
QPixmap QMessageBoxPrivate::standardIcon(QMessageBox::Icon icon, QMessageBox *mb)
{
    QStyle *style = mb ? mb->style() : QApplication::style();
    int iconSize = style->pixelMetric(QStyle::PM_MessageBoxIconSize, 0, mb);
    QIcon tmpIcon;
    switch (icon) {
    case QMessageBox::Information:
        tmpIcon = style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxInformation, 0, mb);
        break;
    case QMessageBox::Warning:
        tmpIcon = style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxWarning, 0, mb);
        break;
    case QMessageBox::Critical:
        tmpIcon = style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxCritical, 0, mb);
        break;
    case QMessageBox::Question:
        tmpIcon = style->standardIcon(QStyle::SP_MessageBoxQuestion, 0, mb);
    default:
        break;
    }
    if (!tmpIcon.isNull())
        return tmpIcon.pixmap(iconSize, iconSize);
    return QPixmap();
}
```

Creating a similar function provides a way to obtain the pixmap for all these message box styles.

Source: http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/37395-Getting-the-Icon-of-a-MessageBox